# Activity code to Fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, slidingdrawer

I had two apps that worked ok. Now I have made a new app which is basically a Navigation Drawer and I'm trying to get those other apps each one into one fragment. When I try to make to adapt the code of the mainactivity of one of the apps, the fragment crashes. No warnings, no errors, just crashes..

I leave you here some code of the fragment (I'm cutting some lines I'm sure that are not the problem):

```
public class SFragment extends Fragment {
    public SFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_s, container, false);

        rdGroup1 = (RadioGroup)getView().findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        rdGroup2 = (RadioGroup)getView().findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);
        cBox1 = (CheckBox)getView().findViewById(R.id.especCB);
        button = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
        list = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        return rootView;
    }

        public String itemValue;

        public String[] values;

        private int espec = 0;
        private int curso = 0;
        private int cuatri = 0;

        private ListView list;

        private RadioGroup rdGroup1;
        private RadioGroup rdGroup2;

        private CheckBox cBox1;
        private Button button;

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


        String[] values = new String[] {};

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

        list.setAdapter(adapter); 


        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
               int position, long id) {


                // ListView Clicked item value
                itemValue = (String) list.getItemAtPosition(position);

                // Show Alert 
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), VistaAsig.class);
                i.putExtra("itemValue", itemValue);

                Log.v("MActivity onCreate","onItemClicklist Intent OK");

                startActivity(i);

                Log.v("MActivity onCreate","onItemClicklist Start OK");


            }

            });

        rdGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                cBox1.setEnabled(true);
                if (checkedId == R.id.radio1){
                    /*No hay especialidades en primero*/
                    curso = 1; cBox1.setEnabled(false);

                }else if (checkedId == R.id.radio2){
                    /*No hay especialidades en segundo*/
                    curso = 2; cBox1.setEnabled(false);
                }else if (checkedId == R.id.radio3){
                    curso = 3;
                }else if (checkedId == R.id.radio4){
                    curso = 4;
                }

                if ((curso != 0)&&(cuatri != 0)) { button.setEnabled(true); }

            }

            });

        rdGroup2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (checkedId == R.id.radio11){
                    cuatri = 1; 
                }else if (checkedId == R.id.radio12){
                    cuatri = 2;
                }

                if ((curso != 0)&&(cuatri != 0)) { button.setEnabled(true); }
            }

        });

        cBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton checkBox, boolean checked) {

             if (espec == 0) espec = 1; else if (espec == 1) espec = 0;
            }
        });

        addData();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In this lines

```
rdGroup1 = (RadioGroup)getView().findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
rdGroup2 = (RadioGroup)getView().findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);
cBox1 = (CheckBox)getView().findViewById(R.id.especCB);
button = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
list = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

Change `getView()` to `rootView`

`getView()` retrieves the view you return in `onCreateView`, but you are still in `onCreateView` so it returns null giving you a NullPointerException making your App crash

Comment: well is hard to debug without the logs but I think you should move this line `DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());` to `onCreateView`

Comment: That's not possible, it gives me a lot of errors in some parts of the code

Comment: I've been using the logs, apparently the problems come from `DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());` but it won't let me change this to `onCreateView`: what could I do?

Answer (score 0):

Clean build then try this:

Change:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

Into: ...(ROOT, SOURCE, DESITNATION)

Example:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.title, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**If you don't get any errors in Logcat then you should use the breakpoints to see when it breaks.**

Comment: I tried that, but nothing changed... Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jorge Alfaro I found the answer to be the following:
You should create the object outside every method as I was doing and initialize the object inside `onCreateView`. So, in a first part you would have:

```
DatabaseHandler db;
```

And inside `onCreateView`:

```
db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
```